# How can I list branches with no descendants in git?

Tags: git

How can I list branches with no descendants in git? I want a way to list all distinct development paths, for example, to determine which branches require merging.

Comment: "Descendants" isn't how git thinks - a commit knows its parents, not its children. What you're really asking is to list all branches for which there are no branches with them as ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
$ git branch --no-merged
```

will show you the names of all branches that haven't been merged into your current branch. Likewise,

```
$ git branch --merged
```

will show you all the branches that *have* been merged into your current branch.

Comment: Not really what I want. Consider branches master, foo and bar where bar is a descendant of foo. I only want bar list (and possibly master if it has any changes not in bar). Your solution would list foo and bar.