# How do I list dangling branches/branch tips in Git?

Tags: git, branch

I have many branches, some of which are remnants of pull requests, others are temporary local branches.

How do I list all the branches that dangle, i.e. are leafs in the git tree?

---

Here is an illustration of what I want, yet the solutions below do not give:

```
  B
 / \
A-C-D
 \
  E-F
```

With this branch layout I want a list like:

- **D**
- **F**

---

These questions do not answer my problem, yet some come close:

- [List branches with no descendents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4818691)
- [List branches containing another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52446266)
- [List branches not merged into master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15577847)
- [git-heads](https://github.com/seschwar/git-heads)

Comment: https://github.com/seschwar/git-heads ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the list of branches not merged into master, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577847/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-branches-not-merged-into-master-ordered-by-most-recent)

Comment: @Mikhail git-heads only show the commits, not the branch names, at least in my testing.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon The answers show how to list branches not merged into a _specific branch_. This includes branches part of the stem.

Comment: Use `git branch --points-at` to find branches by commits

Comment: How do I use `--points-at` with `git-heads`? It uses `git log`.

Comment: Likely there is nothing built in, you will have to chain together multiple commands. A simple way to get started would be `git show-ref --heads`, this will output "HASH refs/heads/branchname" for each branch, and then you will have to pipe that through for instance SED to edit the lines.

Comment: Powershell solution: `git show-ref --heads | Foreach { $_.Split()[1] -replace "^refs/heads/","" }`

Comment:  `git show-ref --heads` would, in my example list `A-F`, i.e. all branches

Comment: Hm, I found this in scripts I've used for something similar but I guess there must be more massaging in the rest of the scripts then. Ignore my comments then, other than the bit about nothing is built in. I don't think there is anything that will do what you want out of the box.

Comment: Something built in would be ideal. Then an elegant one-liner wold be the next-best. Lastly, a home cooked script/external program, would suffice. If you have any of these, I'll be happy to mark it as an answer, if it really works as described.